# How can the image not overflow on the height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, responsive

I want to make the image fit inside the parent div, however, on some screen sizes, the image is overflowing on the height axis.

It's all fine with normal size images, but with huge image, like a 15000 x 10800 image, the image still respects the parent width, but exceeds the height

I can use  `max-height: -webkit-fill-available;` with chrome, but firefox doesn't support `-moz-available` on `max-height`

I am using bootstrap 4, but I made some CSS modifications.

Screenshot:
[image: Broken image]

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="imageZoomModalTitle">Galeria</h5>
        <button type="button" class="custon-close-button-color close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-modal" src="xyz" >
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.modal-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-modal {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Edit**
This is the result I am searching for. That image is using `max-height: -webkit-fill-available;` on the `.img-modal`
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1. Hide the rest of the image with the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property:

```
.modal-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Variant 2: Place the image as a background for the modal body and set the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to `cover` or `contain`.

Is any of these solutions suitable for you?

UPDATE. **Bootstrap 4 modal with a big image as a background**.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/wvKNJPW

```css
.custom-modal .modal-dialog {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 max-width: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.custom-modal .modal-content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 border: 2px;
 border-radius: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.custom-modal .modal-body {
 background: url("http://glebkema.ru/images/glebkema_iphone_9623_w1000.jpg") center / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal custom-modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="imageZoomModalTitle">Galeria</h5>
    <button type="button" class="custon-close-button-color close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gleb, but I want the whole image, and in both ways, the image has been cropped

Comment: @Benevides If you set the image as a background with the `background-size: contain;` property, then it will not be cropped.

Comment: @Benevides I've added a working example solution to my answer. Check, please.